# Magento add new custom option?

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to new custom option as a image. while adding a product i need to add a custom image option filed.

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create a new attribute, select "Media Image" for "Catalog Input Type for Store Owner", and assign it to the appropriate attribute set. Now you have the option to add a new image to the products that have this attribute assigned.

Comment: i am asking for custom option tab under that text area, text field like that i need a column image

Answer (score 0):

Change the custom option's input type to file. 
Please check the screenshot

[image]

For Image in attribute

Goto **Catalog->attributes->Manage attribute->add new attribute**.
Give all details...
For "Catalog Input Type for Store Owner " select Media image and save it.

Then goto manage attribute sets.. 
Select your attribute set. For Example, select Default. Then drag and drop your attribute in that. Save it. Goto product creation page. You will find the image option.

Comment: No actually i need a image option in input type

Comment: The file option supports image too. for example Please check the right bottom of the screenshot regarding maximum image size

Comment: How to upload image

Comment: If you want frontend users to upload image for a product, use custom option.
If you want admin to add custom image while creating product use attribute.

Comment: Admin only add image

Comment: Then follow @Badger 's answer

Comment: How to assign for that image can you please explain i am new to this

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check it.

Comment: ok but i want under to custom option in input type drop down

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are describing is swatches. Which you can only use in Configurable products at the moment. Maybe depending on your product type this might be a better method to use?

Alternatively, if you are set on using custom options and if you don't want to build in the module yourself you can choose one from the marketplace:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?q=Option+Swatches&pl=0